# Singleton generic implementation of simple LinkedList

Tags: c#, linked-list, generics, singleton

I would like to ask if the implementation is ok, and what I can improve.
Although I'm not sure if the Singleton is working properly.

```
class MyLinkedList<T>
{
    class Node<G>
    {
        public Node<G> next;
        public G Data;
        public Node(G data)
        {
            Data = data;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;

    public T First => head.Data;
    public T Last => tail.Data;

    public MyLinkedList()
    {
        head = tail = null;
    }

    public void Add(T data)
    {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(data);

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = node;
            tail = node;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.next = node;
            tail = node;
        }

    }
    public void RemoveByIndex(int index)
    {
        int count = 0;
        Node<T> current = head;
        Node<T> previous = current;

        try
        {
            while (count <= index)
            {
                if (count == index)
                {
                    previous.next = current.next;
                    current = null;
                }

                else
                {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid index to remove");
        }

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder();
        Node<T> index = head;
        while (index.next != null)
        {
            list.Append($"{index.Data} -> ");
            index = index.next;
        }
        list.Append(index.Data);

        return list.ToString();
    }
}

public class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private Singleton() { }

    private static readonly Lazy<T> instance = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());
    public static T Instance { get { return instance.Value; } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `Add` does `tail = node` in both branches. Take it out:

  ```
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            tail.next = node;
        }
        tail = node;
  ```
- Depending on `index`, `RemoveByIndex` may remove `head`, or `tail` (or both). If it happens, `head`, or `tail` (or both) members must be adjusted.
- In `RemoveByIndex`, a condition `count == index` is mostly false. It is true exactly once, and when it is true, the loop gets broken. Again, be explicit:

  ```
    public void RemoveByIndex(int index) {
        int count = 0;
        Node<T> current = head;
        Node<T> previous = current;

        try {
            while (count < index) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
                count++;
            }
            previous.next = current.next;
            current = null;
        } catch(....) {
            ....
        }
    }
  ```
- Catching the `NullReferenceException` in `RemoveByIndex` is wrong. The caller is not informed that the removal failed. It does not know or care what `RemoveByIndex` did print. Let the caller handle the problem.

Comment: Ok thank you for feedback, I improved things as you said, but I encountered a problem, when i call RemoveByIndex(0) it does nothing. I don't really know why.